Controlling email delivery in Talend job


I need to send emails to multiple users based on the email addresses in the file. I have To email Id and the BCC email ids in the file. The file is a pipe delimited file. The records in the file look as below.
First field is a TO email and a Pipe which separates the column and then BCC emails.
rama.shetti@abcxz.com|man1234555@gmail.com;rtham77788877@gmail.com srinivas@abcxz.com|al777778888@yahoo.com
My requirement is, I should send an email to Rama.Shetti and to the two email ids in the BCC column.
I should send second email to Srinivas and the BCC email in the next column.
But, when I tried, the jobs is sending two emails to rama. He is receiving Srinivas email also.


Hi, I don't really understand what you're trying to do in your tJava, are you trying to concat all emailID and bcc to send only one email ? And also can you show the output of the tLogRow_1 ?

Hi, Thank you for the response.  I dont see anything in the Tlogrow. here is the output of this job.                                                                                                                               Starting job User_Deactivation_EmailTest at 08:34 23/07/2024.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4009
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job User_Deactivation_EmailTest ended at 08:34 23/07/2024. [Exit code  = 0]

I don't want to concat email ids. I want to send emails to individuals.

I am expecting to receive one email per recipient. But I am getting two emails for two rows.

Added images to show how I am receiving the emails. I want to receive one email. But I am receiving two emails. First email with one email address and the second email with two email addresses. I am a bit new to this and may b I am doing something wrong. Please let me know if there is any simple way here

The requirement is, if the file (emails file) has 100 rows, each row is a separate email id and its associates BCC emails. And the job should send 100 individual emails as per each email id and Bcc list in that row

And on the other hand if the file has less than a 100 row, what is the expected beahvior ?

Thank you. FlowIterate has taken care of that.
